# Validating dropdownlist inside gridview control

Tags: asp.net

for testing i have tried customvalidation

```
function ClientValidate(sender, args) { 
       //return false for testing...
       args.IsValid = false;

    }

 <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidator1" ControlToValidate="ddldetail"
                        Text="Please select" ValidateEmptyText="true"    
                        ClientValidationFunction="ClientValidate"  
                        Display="Dynamic">     
                    </asp:CustomValidator>
```

edit: here is what i exaclty wants to happen:

[image]

how to validate a dropdownlist and i have done this zillion times but what i am doing wrong here? any second pair of eye might spot it? i am trying to validate the dropdownlist if the user have not select any help?

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btn_Click"  CausesValidation="true"/>

<asp:GridView ID="GVInputMapping" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id"
                     EnableModelValidation="True" onrowdatabound="GVInputMapping_RowDataBound">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" ControlStyle-Width="250px" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddldetail">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">Select me</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">abc</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">GHt</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="requiredDDL" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="ddldetail" ErrorMessage="Please select" InitialValue="Select me"  Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `InitialValue` of the validator set to *Select me*, but the *Value* of that item is actually `0`:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select Me" Value="0" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Foo" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Bar" Value="2" />
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" 
    ErrorMessage="Please select" 
    InitialValue="0"        
    Display="Dynamic">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

You'll also need to assign a unique validation group for each row, otherwise validation will kick off for every row. To assign a unique validation group, you can use the `Id` column:

```
ValidationGroup='<%# string.Format("Group_{0}", Eval("Id")) %>'
```

You would add this to the validator and the button in the row.

Comment: i do have if you look at the html code `<asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">Select me</asp:ListItem> `

Comment: That's the *text*, not the *value*. If you don't set a value, the text will be assigned as the value, but in this case you set the value to `0`.

Comment: You can test my theory by changing the `InitialValue` to `0`. Your validator should start working once you do that.

Comment: so now its showing the `errormessage="please select"` on all the rows

Comment: Okay, that's an entirely different problem. You need to assign a unique `ValidationGroup` to each row.

Comment: meaning that instead of showing on that particular row its showing on all the rows of that column in the gridview

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of how to assign a unique validation group to each row.

Comment: so i have seen in the page source that it does have a unique validationgroup after i applied ur code, but the validation is not working, instead of throwing me an errormessage it does execute the code

Comment: so if i remove the validationgroup then its showing the errormessage but its on all the rows of the gridview as i said in my above post

Comment: See my updated answer. I didn't tell you to remove the validation group. I said the validaiton group needs to be unique for each row, and I provided an example of how to do that.

Comment: James: i was just testing to see what makes my code not working... and if i have validationgroup then the validation is not working... i put it back the validationgroup and i do see that i am getting unique ids when i view the page source but the validation is not working then i thought to try with customvalidation (i update my question) and now its working with groupvalidation but the problem is that iam getting errormessage on every row.... instead of what row i have selected

Comment: i am thinking may be my submit button is outside the gridview because of that? i cant believe that i am stuck with this silly validation ergggg

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11071/discussion-between-user1234271-and-james-johnson)

Comment: `You would add this to the validator and the button in the row` my button is outside the gridview... thats what i have been trying to say :)

Comment: Okay, we need to move this into a separate question, because the moderators are going to lock this soon if we don't. Also, the question is entirely different now, and it will lose context if we continue. Mark the answer and create a new one, and we'll see what we can do to figure it out.

Comment: new question i posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524993/how-to-trigger-custom-validation-in-gridview